# Dados en python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear un programa que lance `n` numero de dados `n` veces, pero me marca un error

```
nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))

nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? "))

import random

td = [0]*(5*nd+1)

for i in range (nv):

    s = 0
    for ii in range (nd):
        s += random.randint(nd,(6*nd))
    td[s-nd]+=1
print(td)
```

Comment: ¿Qué error le marca ?

Comment: Los dados solo caen en 0 y 1, por muchas veces que este corra y aun cuando no deben caer en 0

Comment: `td = [0]*(5*nd+1)` creará un `array`  lleno de ceros y al final solo suma 1 a la posición en `td[s-nd]+=1` .¿Qué intenta lograr ?  no debería ser simplemente 
`td = [0]*(nd*nv)` en la inicialización?

Answer (score 0):

El mayor error esta en `td[s-nd]+=1`, esto llega a provocar que intentes incluso acceder a indices fuera de rango. En caso de que esto no pase, el valor de un elemento de la lista no guardara la salida de `random`. Debería ser algo como `td[i] = s`.

Ademas de esto, mezclas varias posibles aproximaciones al problema en una, vamos a ver varias opciones a ver si queda algo en claro:

- Lista con `n` lanzamientos en los que cada elemento es la suma de los dados, una llamada a `random` por cada lanzamiento:

  - Usando indices:

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? "))

    td = [0] * nv
    for i in range (nv):
        td[i] = random.randint(nd, (6 * nd))
    print(td)
    ```
  - Usando `list.append`:

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? "))

    td = []
    for _ in range (nv):
        td.append(random.randint(nd, (6 * nd)))
    print(td)
    ```
  - Listas por compresión:

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? "))

    td = [random.randint(nd, (6 * nd)) for _ in range(nv)]
    print(td)
    ```
- Lista con `n` lanzamientos en los que cada elemento es la suma de los dados, una llamada a `random` por cada dado.

  - Usando indices:

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? ")) 

    td = [0] * nv
    for i in range (nv):
        for _ in range(nd):
            td[i] += random.randint(1,  6)
    print(td)
    ```
  - Usando `list.append`:

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? ")) 

    td = []
    for _ in range (nv):
        s = 0
        for _ in range(nd):
            s += random.randint(1,  6)
        td.append(s)
    print(td)
    ```
  - Usando compresión de listas:

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? "))

    td = [sum(random.randint(1,  6) for _ in range(nd)) for _ in range(nv)]
    print(td)
    ```
- Una lista con una lista anidada por cada tirada conteniendo el valor de cada uno de los dados.

  - Usando indices:

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? "))


    td = [[0] * nd for _ in range (nv)]
    for i in range (nv):
        for j in range(nd):
            td[i][j] = random.randint(1,  6)
    print(td)
    ```
  - Usando `list.append`

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? "))


    td = []
    for _ in range (nv):
        s = []
        for _ in range(nd):
            s.append(random.randint(1,  6))
        td.append(s)
    print(td)
    ```
  - Usando compresión de listas

    ```
    nd = int(input("Cuantos dados quieres tirar? "))
    nv = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres tirar los dados? "))


    td = [[random.randint(1,  6) for _ in range(nd)] for _ in range(nv)]
    print(td)
    ```

Cabe decir que las listas por compresión son sin duda las opciones mas eficientes.

Para las dos primeras aproximaciones obtenemos para 2 dados y 5 tiradas por ejemplo:

```
[8, 4, 11, 5, 7]
```

Para la ultima:

```
[[2, 1], [2, 3], [5, 5], [6, 4], [3, 5]]
```